# Perfect (Server-Side Swift) view engines

Tags: perfect, server-side-swift

In `NodeJS` we have view engines (`mustache`, `pug` and etc.) and we can setup and use any of them. Does Perfect has any (default or installable) view engine with features like `Layout Setting`, `Partial Views` and other features?

I read about Perfect-Mustache in Perfect documentation, but I think it is not clarify how to use this, or how to separate views (`.mustache or .html` files) from other files, and how to render them.

Comment: Sharing a link http://perfect.org/docs/mustache.html - not sure it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example to answer your question: Perfect-Blog-Mustache, a Perfect CMS demo:

https://github.com/PerfectExamples/Perfect-Blog-Mustache